# Magento 2.3 - Overide \magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\xx.xml

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

Is there anyway to override and not change directly the

```
 \magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\xx.xml ?
```

This is so that I can change the decimal denoter from "," to "." for stores that use comma as decimal .

Comment: Did you get any solution??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change timezone then you can look from below options:

1. STORES -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options, Here we can change the 'Timezone' field by switching to required store.
2. We can also set timezone in app/bootstrap.php file by below code:

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
   ```
3. If you can explain your scenario then we can see it further.

Comment: Have updated my question with more detail.